# How 2 set up a bunch of modules for sell per node access?

Tags: ubercart, users

I need to sell some nodes on my site, not type of content (subscription alredy exist) - only per node acess. 
I think, that it is not cost-effective to create type of content for every good, cause number of goods can reach 100 units per day.
I know, that https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_node_access can resolve my trouble, but I develop my site under 7 version of Drupal, and uc_node_access for 7 has only sanbox now.
Dear experts, help me if u can, I'm not a professional developer.
P.S. - sorry if my post has grammar mistakes, I'm Russian.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it successfully. Resolving my problem on https://www.drupal.org/node/2407311